# Migrate from Google's sw-toolbox to Workbox SW (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, service-worker, sw-precache, sw-toolbox, workbox

I used to use `sw-toolbox` for management of my service worker - small, simple, effective. Now that Google have released `Workbox SW` (which replaces sw-toolbox and sw-precache) I need to migrate, but am battling to find:

a) single .js dependency for Workbox that I can include in my project
b) a custom build tool to build a single .js dependency
c) a way to include the Workbox build in my project build

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: In an effort to improve the content of SO, a comment/reason for the down-vote would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two useful references:
http://leruplund.dk/2017/04/15/setting-up-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-with-npm-webpack-and-typescript-part-i/
and
https://workboxjs.org/how_tos/workbox-cli.html

Or just follow the 4 steps below

**Step 1:** Install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/
**Step 2:** Initialize NPM on your project by opening command prompt on your project root and running the command `npm init -y`
**Step 3:** From the same location at your command prompt, install Workbox with NPM by running the command `npm install workbox-cli --global`
**Step 4:** Generate a service worker by running the command `workbox-cli generate:sw`

Having fiddled around a some hours, I was disappointed to note that the Workbox base dependency is 3x bigger than sw-toolbox - so, if size is critical to your project (which it often is for 3rd world market) then keep this in mind (sw-toolbox is 16kb, workbox is 48kb)

sw-toolbox works just fine for me at the moment, so I'm going to go back to it until I can work out how to get the size of Workbox a bit smaller.

However, I hope this helps someone else in the meantime :)